# update values through modal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, spring-mvc

I want update by opening modal.the already entered values not displaying in modal .using backend as springmvc and mongodb

this is piece of code i written

```
<a href="#"  type="button"  data-toggle="modal" ng-click="editLink(blog,$index)"  class="icon bb-edit"  type="button"> edit </a>
```

controller.js:editLink function will open and show modal

```
  $scope.currentObject = [];
$scope.blog = [];

     $scope.editLink = function (currObj, index) {
                                    $scope.isInEditMode = true;
                                    $scope.blog = angular.copy(currObj);
                                    $scope.index = index;

                                   $('#editBlog').modal('show');

                                };
```

and this is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBlog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                 <section class="create create-blog">
    <p class="create-heading color-black">Update Blog</p>
    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    </div>
    <div class="create-beats clearfix">

      <div class="editor-section navbar-left">
        <input type="text" name="blogtitle" class="form-control" id="blogtitle" placeholder="Enter Title Here" ng-model="blog.title">
         <p ng-bind="blog.title"></p>
        <div class='create-beats-edit editor'>
          <textarea class="summernote" id="summernote"></textarea>
        </div><!-- eo editor-->
       <!--  <div>
        <form method="post">
                        <textarea id="elm1" name="area" ng-model="blog.description"></textarea>
                    </form>
        </div> -->          
        <div class="panel-group accordion-main">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion-main" href="#locationcollapse">
                Default Location + Checked in option<i class="pull-right icon bb-arrow-down"></i>
              </a>
            </div><!-- eo panel-title -->
            <div id="locationcollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body" id="locationDiv">
                <ui-select ng-model="address.selected" theme="bootstrap"
                                        ng-disabled="disabled" reset-search-input="false"> 
                                        <match placeholder="{{defaultadd}}">{{$select.selected.formatted_address}}</match>
                                    <choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index"
                                        refresh="refreshAddresses($select.search)" refresh-delay="0">
                                    <div
                                        ng-bind-html="address.formatted_address | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                                    </choices> </ui-select>
                                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


       <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion-main" href="#categorycollapse">
                    Categories<i class="pull-right icon bb-arrow-down"></i>
                  </a>
                </div><!-- eo panel-title -->
                <div id="categorycollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6"   >
                        <select name="blog.category" ng-model="blog.category" class="form-control" ng-options="item.name for item in categories"
                                                    ng-change="onCategoryChange()">
                          <option value="">Categories</option>

                        </select>
                        <!-- <select name ="category" ng-model="blog.category">

                           <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                        </select> -->

                      </div><!-- eo col -->

                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <select name="blog.subCategory" ng-model="blog.c" class="form-control" ng-options="item.name for item in subcategories" ng-change="onCategoryChange()">
                          <option value="">Sub categories</option>

                        </select>
                      </div><!-- eo col -->
                    </div><!-- eo row -->
                  </div><!-- eo panel-body -->
                </div><!-- eo #categorycollapse -->
              </div><!-- eo panel panel-default -->
            </div><!-- eo col -->

            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion-main" href="#tagscollapse">
                    Tags<i class="pull-right icon bb-arrow-down"></i>
                  </a>
                </div><!-- eo panel-title -->
                <div id="tagscollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                   <!--  <textarea id="onlyTags"> -->

                                                <!-- <script src="js/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script> -->
                                                <!-- <input type="text" ng-model="blog.labels" id="labels" value="Amsterdam,Washington" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Add tags" /> -->
                                                <!-- <link href="css/angular-tags-0.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                                <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
                                                <!-- <tags
                                                    data-options="{addable: true, classes: {white: 'black', red: 'red'}}"
                                                    data-src="s as s.name for s in sourceTags"
                                                    data-model="selectedLabels"></tags> -->
                                                    <tags-input ng-model="sourceTags"></tags-input>
                                            <!-- </textarea> -->
                    <p><i>Separate tags with commas</i></p>
                  </div><!-- eo panel-body -->
                </div><!-- eo #tagscollapse -->
              </div><!-- eo panel panel-default -->
            </div><!-- eo col -->
       </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion-main" href="#timebeatscollapse">
                    TimeBeats <i class="pull-right icon bb-arrow-down"></i>
                  </a>
                </div><!-- eo panel-title -->
                <div id="timebeatscollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="input-group date form_meridian_datetime" id="datetimepicker">
                      <input type="text" name="Date"  ng-model="blog.timeBeats" class="form-control beat-time-panel" value="">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <a class="btn btn-default date-set" type="button"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></a>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div><!-- eo panel-body -->
                </div><!-- eo #timebeatscollapse -->
              </div><!-- eo panel panel-default -->
            </div><!-- eo col -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion-main" href="#ratingcollapse">
                    Rating<i class="pull-right icon bb-arrow-down"></i>
                  </a>
                </div><!-- eo panel-title -->
                <div id="ratingcollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="blog.rating" ng-model="blog.rating" value="16+">&nbsp; Above 16</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="blog.rating" ng-model="blog.rating" value="-16">&nbsp; Below 16</label>
                  </div><!-- eo panel-body -->
                </div><!-- eo #ratingcollapse -->
              </div><!-- eo panel panel-default -->
            </div><!-- eo col -->

          </div><!-- eo row -->

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion-main" href="#publishcollapse">
             Share<i class="pull-right icon bb-arrow-up"></i>
              </a>
            </div><!-- eo panel-title -->
            <div id="publishcollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                  Visibility: <strong>Public</strong>
                  <a onclick="document.getElementById('visibility').style.display='';return false;" href="" style="border-bottom:1px dotted blue;">Edit</a>
                </p>
                <div id="visibility" style="display:none;margin:15px 15px 0px 15px;padding:5px;" ng-init="blog.visibility='Public'">
                  <label><input type="radio"  ng-model="blog.visibility" value="Public" >&nbsp; Public</label>
                  <label><input type="radio"  ng-model="blog.visibility" value="Private">&nbsp; Private</label>
                  <label><input id='password-protect' type="radio"  ng-model="blog.visibility" value="Password">&nbsp; Password Protected</label>                 
                  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ">Ok</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('visibility').style.display='none';return false;" href="" >Cancel</a>
                  <div id='pdp-show-me' style='display:none'>
                    Password: <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:233px;" placeholder="Enter your password" name="enter_password" ng-model="blog.visibilityPassword">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group date form_advance_datetime" >
                  Published on: <input type="text" name="beat-time" class="beat-time-panel published-input" ng-model="blog.publishedOn" value="">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <a class="btn date-set" type="button"><span>Edit</span></a>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="shareIn" >
                  Share on: 
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" >&nbsp; Facebook</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox">&nbsp; Twitter</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox">&nbsp; Google+</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox">&nbsp; Linkedin</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox">&nbsp; Pinterest</label></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>


              </div><!-- eo panel-body -->
            </div><!-- eo #publishcollapse -->
          </div><!-- eo panel panel-default -->

                <div class="editor-buttons text-center">
                <form role="form">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitBlog('PREVIEW')">Preview</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitBlog('DRAFT')">Draft</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="clearAll()">Clear</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitBlog('PUBLISHED')">Publish</button>
               </form>
                </div><!-- eoeditor-buttons -->
          </div></div>

                <div class="editor-aside-section navbar-right">

        <div class="panel-group accordion-aside">
```

My problem is already stored blog.title and all fields not reflecting in modal.

Please help.

Comment: To me it seems like scope issue for modal . Please create a fiddle for same .

Comment: Are you using angular bootstrap ui ??

Comment: ya m using angular bootstrap